# Как сделать чередование записываемых в файл значений

Tags: c++, файлы

Компоненты файла f –  целые (отличные от нуля) числа,  причем десять идущих подряд положительных чисел чередуются с десятью отрицательными числами и т. д. Получить файл g, в котором записано сначала пять положительных чисел, затем пять отрицательных и т.д.

Числа из f: 10 3 4 1 2 7 2 8 5 2 -1 -2 -5 -6 -2 -9 -1 -21 -12 -42;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;


int main()

{
    int *a = new int;
    int i = 0,n=0;
    int count = 0;

    ifstream f("f.txt");
    if (f.is_open()) {
        while (!f.eof()) {
            f >> a[i];
            i++;
            n++;//подсчет количества чисел в файле
        }

    }
    else {
        cout << "файл не надйен ";
    }
    f.close();
    cout << endl;
    int *plus = new int[n / 2];
    int *minus = new int[n / 2];
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (a[k] > 0) {
            plus[k] = a[k];
            cout << plus[k] << " ";
        }                          //запись в отдельные массиввы полож и отр чисел
        else {
            minus[k] = a[k];
            cout << minus[k] << " ";
        }
    }

    ofstream g("g.txt");
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
         if (count < 5) {
             g<<plus[c]<< " ";
             count++;
        }  // запись в файл g
         else if (c >= 5) {
             if (count % 10 == 0) {
                 count = 0;
                 break;
             }
             g << minus[c]<< " ";
             count++;
         }
    }
    g.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так получили файл или нет? В чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: 10 3 4 1 2 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 
Вот что получается

Comment: `if (c >= 5) { ... g << minus[c] }` как думаете, чему равно `minus[5]`?

Comment: Как вариант последний  `minus[c]` заменить на   `minus[c-5]`